# Proving a Function is bijective function

Tags: discrete-mathematics

didn't succeeded to prove this function is a bijective function: 
$$
f \in \mathbb{N} x \mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}
$$
$$
f = \lambda <a,b>\in \mathbb{N} x \mathbb{N} . \frac {1}{2}(a+b)(a+b+1)+a 
$$

I need to prove that f is injective and surjective but i didn't find any way to do it. i really could use your help. thanks

Comment: I assume you mean $f(a,b)=\frac{1}{2}(a+b)(a+b+1)+a$, right?

Comment: and I suggest using $\times$ instead of $x$ in your notation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Surjectivity

By induction:

base case

$(0,0) = 0$

Suppose there is an $(a,b)$ such that $\lambda (a,b) = n$

We must show that there is some combination $(p,q)$ such that $\lambda (p,q) = n+1$

If $b\ne 0$ then $\lambda (a+1, b-1) = \lambda (a,b) + 1.$

$\lambda(a+1,b-1) = \frac 12 (a+1+b-1)(a+1+b-1+1) + a+1 = \frac 12 (a+b)(a+b) + a+1 = \lambda (a,b) + 1$

If $b = 0,$ then $\lambda (0, a+1) = n + 1$

$\lambda (0, a+1)=\frac 12 (a+1)(a+2) = \frac 12 (a+1)(a) + a+1 = \lambda (a,0) + 1$

This implies $\lambda (a,b)$ is surjective.

Injection, there is probably a cleaner way, but this it what I came up with.

if $\lambda$ is injective, 
$\lambda (a,b) = \lambda (p,q) \implies (a,b) = (p,q)$

By contradiction

Assume $\lambda (a,b) = \lambda (p,q),$ and $(a,b) \ne (p,q)$

WLOG $a+b \ge p+q$

If $a+b = p+q$

$\lambda (a,b)- \lambda (p,q)= a-p=0\\
a=p, b=q$

If $a+b > p+q$

$\lambda (a,b) - \lambda (p,q) = \left (\sum_\limits{n=p+q+1}^{a+b} n\right)+a-p\ge a+b + a -p > 0$

In either case we have a contradiction.

Comment: proving by induction that λ(a,b) is surjective its really creative. when would you advise using it? (of course only if the image of the function or relative with power of א0 but is there another hint?)

Comment: Induction is a handy tool to show that something is true for all natural numbers.  (It is a defining characteristic of $\mathbb N$)  Anyway, what I show here was what is required to prove premise.  I did not show my preliminary noodling around.  Trying values of a, b until I realized that I could build this table:

$\\\begin {array} &&&0&1&2&3\\\\0&&0&1&3&6\\1&&2&4&7\\2&&5&8\end{array}$  And,  how would I describe that?